# Display specific tags by ID in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

How do I display a specific tags in WordPress? I want to display tags with the an ID of 5, 96, 3, etc. The below code works, but displays all tags.

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $tags = get_tags(5);
    if ( $tags ) :
        foreach ( $tags as $tag ) : ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $tag->name ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $tag->name ); ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass additional arguments to [`get_tags()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags#Parameters) which includes the `include` parameter:

> **include**
>   Default is an empty string. A comma- or space-delimited string of term ids to include in the return array.

The documentation for `get_tags()` states you should use a string, but an array is also supported (see addendum below).

Your updated code would be:

```
<ul>
    <?php
    $args = array( 'include' => array( 5, 96, 3 ) );
    $tags = get_tags( $args );
    if ( $tags ) :
        foreach ( $tags as $tag ) : ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $tag->name ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $tag->name ); ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

---

**Addendum:** The documentation for `get_tags()` is out of date. It specifies you should use a string, but an array (as per my code) is also supported. `get_tags()` is a wrapper function for the [`wp_term_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/#parameters) class which supports a string or array:

> **'include'**
>   *(array|string)* Array or comma/space-separated string of term ids to include. Default empty array.

Comment: An array of terms is not a "comma- or space-delimited string". I haven't tried it, but your answer is different to what you've quoted there.

Comment: Wow, it worked, thanks for your help @KirkBeard . yep the docs for get_tags is out of date, they should update it... many thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the [`get_tags()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags) function incorrectly. To include specific tags, use it like this:

```
$tags = get_tags(array('include' => '5,96,3'));
```